# Как использовать лямбда-выражения в Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, лямбда-выражение

Как использовать лямбда выражения в Java 8?
Я не понимаю, как использовать лямбда-выражения.
Нахожу примеры в Интернете, но они как бы для частного случая, и непонятно, как оно работает.
К примеру, вот это:

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
numbers.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Не нашел примера для String.  
К примеру, хочу лямбда-выражением сделать сравнение, если в этом слове находится определенное слово, то распечатать его на консоль.
Можете ли мне объяснить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
        stringList.add("Кот");
        stringList.add("Пёс");
        stringList.add("Котопёс");

        List<String> resultList = stringList.stream()
                        .filter(value -> value.startsWith("Кот"))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
        resultList.forEach(value -> System.out.println(value));
```

Comment: `.collect(Collectors.toList())` - лишний, можно сразу `forEach` использовать. `value -> System.out.println(value)` - избыточно, можно оставить только `System.out::println`.

Comment: @fori1ton

    Arrays.asList("Кот", "Пёс", "Котопёс")
            .stream()
            .filter(v -> v.startsWith("Кот"))
            .forEach(System.out::println);

Comment: @Deadkenny, благодарю, сей код услаждает мой взор. Как всё-таки здорово, что до Java добрались лямбды!

Comment: @fori1ton, всего-то двадцать лет подождать надо было!

http://zahardzhan.github.io/2010/clojure-hooks.html

Answer (score 10):

Почему бы вам не прекратить обучаться по примерам и не почитать какую-нибудь литературу, в которой подробно объясняется принцип работы лямбда-выражений в Java? Эта тема слишком обшираня, чтобы её можно было более-менее полно описать в рамках ответа на форуме.

Лямбды хорошо описаны в [этой статье](http://habrahabr.ru/post/224593/). А если хотите подробнее, почитайте книги, например, [эту](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/27615252/) или [эту](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/31249554/).

Comment: Я читал эти статьи и примеры тоже, но я все равно не понял, как можно сделать то, что я хочу, как я понял, передается метод в данный объект, я бы хотел передать метод в объект класса String, и если там определнное слово, то распечатать его, может быть, так пойму, я обратился сюда после многих попыток понять лямбда-выражения.

Comment: @eldqs, меня сильно смущает ваша лексика. В частности, я не совсем понимаю выражение "передать метод в объект класса String". Если вам нужно напечатать строку, если в ней есть определённое слово, то зачем вообще лямбды?

    if (str.indexOf("word") != -1) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }

Если же вам нужно проделать это с коллекцией строк, то читайте про Stream API, в частности про методы `filter` и `forEach`.

Comment: Я тоже не понял, что вообще хочет ТС, но постеснялся спросить. :)

Comment: @fori1ton да это просто для примера хотел увидеть такое, я понимаю, что можно сделать по-другому

Comment: Есть ещё 2 хорошие книги по Java 8 на русском: [вот эта](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/30196193/) и [вот эта](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/28001133/).