# Лямбда-выражения в Java

Tags: java, лямбда-выражение

Что такое лямбда-выражение и где оно применяется?

Comment: Более конкретный вопрос?

Comment: https://habr.com/post/224593/

Comment: @bulbum данный ресурс как раз и создан для того, чтобы агрегировать знания в одном месте, поэтому я считаю указанный вопрос вполне уместным.

Answer (score 8):

Лямбда-выражения - это новая особенность Java 8 (как и [ссылки на методы](https://vertex-academy.com/tutorials/ru/java-8-ssylki-na-metody/)), которая позволяет реализовать частичный функциональный сахар, если так можно выразиться. Другими словами, лямбды позволяют немного оторваться от стандартной парадигмы в Java - ООП, и добавить в язык немного функциональности, сделать его более гибким.

Собственно, лямбда-выражения созданы в первую очередь, чтобы упростить написание кода. А сами по себе - они очень схожи с анонимными классами.

Думаю, проще будет понять по примеру. Допустим, Вы хотите создать и запустить новый поток. Вы можете сделать это несколькими способами:

- Создать класс, имплементрирующий **функциональный** интерфейс Runnable и добавить экземпляр оного в параметры Thread'а
- Создать анонимный класс непосредственно внутри параметров конструктора Thread'а
- Использовать это самое ноу-хау и написать всё через лямбды

Первое:

```
class RunnableImpl implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello world from new thread");
    }
}
  ...
  ...

 Thread thread = new Thread(new RunnableImpl()); // Обычное использование объекта класса
```

Второе:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Анонимный класс упрощает код и добавляет функциональность
                System.out.println("Hello world from new thread");
            }
        });
```

Третье:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() -> System.out.println("Hello world from new thread via lambda")); // Как видим, тут очень всё просто
```

Затем, для каждого из данных примеров вызываем `thread.start();` и наслаждаемся результатом.

Как видно из 3-его примера, в основе лямбд лежит особый синтаксис (вот это непонятное `() ->`). Для того чтобы понять это, вначале нужно вообще осознать, в каких случаях используются лямбды, вернее, где это допустимо синтаксисом языка. Я подчеркнул одно важное слово - **функциональный интерфейс**, именно на основе этого и работают лямбды. Функциональный интерфейс - это такой интерфейс, у которого всего один метод (как у Runnable только один метод run).
Можно написать свой собственный функциональный интерфейс. Вот:

```
interface CalculateEngine {
    double add(double a, double b);
}
```

И затем, воспользоваться лямбдами

```
 CalculateEngine calculateEngine = ((a, b) -> a + b);
 System.out.println(calculateEngine.add(4.5, 3.2)); // 7.7
```

Аналогично можно провернуть это через анонимные классы (чтобы лучше понять, что да как)

```
CalculateEngine calculateEngine = new CalculateEngine() {
    @Override
    public double add(double a, double b) {
        return a + b;
    }
};
System.out.println(calculateEngine.add(4.5, 3.2)); // 7.7
```

**Можно сделать вывод**, что лямбда-выражения применяются там, где это удобно. Создание потоков, работа с коллекциями. Везде, где за основу взяты функциональный интерфейсы.

P.S: Ещё, хотел бы Вам сказать, что подобные вещи лучше читать в разных книгах/статьях и etc. Так-же, похожие вопросы уже [задавали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/408856/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-java-8). Очень важно уметь [гуглить](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html#overview).

Comment: Мне кажется, что в ответе стоит сделать особый акцент, что это именно (и только) синтаксический сахар. Плюс немного расписать о том, что лямбда (я сейчас не только про java-реализацию) подразумевает также замыкания (заострить внимание на область видимости `this` внутри лямбды) . К примеру в `rust` обычная функция не может захватить значения извне, а вот лямбда может.

Comment: @Темкатоже, ну, я просто сделал небольшой, можно сказать, обзор на лямбды. С примерами и сравнениями. Всё остальное можно уже найти по желанию

Алсо, замыкания вообще штука интересная :)